# Typescript/Angular printing out object array elements and grabbing specific elements

Tags: javascript

[image: The Array]

This is what appears when I do

```
console.log(projects)
```

However, whenever I try to print anything beyond that, I receive errors or it simply does not print anything.

The things I have tried:

```
console.log(projects[0]);
console.log(projects.title);
```

I have also tried using the for each element loop to no luck.

How would I grab the title of each element within this?

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Beware: this might be async. Can you please show the code which is populating the `projects` variable?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a school project and deals with other students' data and so I do not wish to post my code. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
console.log(projects[0].title);
```

First you need to access first array element and after the property

and for the foreach :

```
projects.forEach(projet=>console.log(projet.title));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array with forEach and log the title of each objects.

```
const myArray = [{title: 'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}, {title: 'title3'}];

myArray.forEach(object => console.log(object.title));
```

You can find the documentation of forEach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).